# SQL Server trigger only on changes to update a calculated column

Tags: sql-server, triggers

For a time scheduling project, I have two tables: `tbl_timeslots` which holds available times with `slotid` as the primary key and `totalmembers` which counts the number of appointments made for this slot, and `tbl_appointments` with primary key `apptid` which holds the actual appointments, with `slotid` as a foreign key linking to the slot information.

I need to automatically update the `totalmembers` column any time an appointment is created/deleted/changed. The trigger I wrote (shown below) does not update the correct number of appointments in the `tbl_timeslots` column `totalmembers`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_timeslots
(
    slotid int ,
    fromdate datetime ,
    todate datetime ,
    totalmembers int 
)

INSERT tbl_timeslots (slotid, fromdate, todate, totalmembers) 
VALUES (1, '2016-01-01 10:00:00', '2016-01-01 11:00:00', 0)
INSERT tbl_timeslots (slotid, fromdate, todate, totalmembers) 
VALUES (2, '2016-01-01 11:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:00:00', 0)

CREATE TABLE tbl_appointments
(
    apptid int ,
    slotid int ,
    firstname varchar(10) ,
    lastname varchar(10) 
)

INSERT tbl_appointments (apptid, slotid, firstname, lastname) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'Mark', 'Twain')
INSERT tbl_appointments (apptid, slotid, firstname, lastname)  
VALUES (2, 1, 'Thomas', 'Jefferson')
INSERT tbl_appointments (apptid, slotid, firstname, lastname) 
VALUES (3, 2, 'Donald', 'Duck')


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_totalmembers] 
ON [dbo].[TBL_appointments]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_timeslots 
    SET totalmembers = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                        FROM tbl_appointments a 
                        WHERE tbl_timeslots.slotid = a.slotid) 
    FROM inserted i 
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.apptid = d.apptid 
    WHERE
        d.slotid <> i.slotid 
        AND (tbl_timeslots.slotid = i.slotid OR tbl_timeslots.slotid = d.slotid)
END
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, and explain what "does not work" mean.

Comment: Too low or too high? is it a multiple? Its also helpful to add a 'update datetime' column to your target table and update it as an audit. Do you get the correct number if you remove everything after (and including) `FROM inserted i`

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the trigger a bit and it worked for me :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_totalmembers] 
ON [dbo].[TBL_appointments]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_timeslots 
SET totalmembers = a.cnt 
from 
(
SELECT slotid,COUNT(1) as cnt 
 FROM tbl_appointments 
 group by slotid
 ) a
WHERE
   tbl_timeslots.slotid=a.slotid
 END
```

Or in case if there is a specific problem please mention so that we could look into it .

Comment: When using the trigger you wrote if I make any update to tbl_appointments I get an error "No row was updated,,,,The row value(s)  updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows (3 rows).

Comment: Also, please note that there are many more fields on tbl_appointments and most updates (95%) will not change the slotid. Therefore I only want to  update the field totalmembers if the field slotid was changed in tbl_appointments (and also if the row was added or deleted)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what Update did you issue on the Tbl_appointments because for me it is working fine

Comment: First I tried changing a slotid from 1 to zero in tbl_appointments for a record, when that didnt work I tried just editing the name of a person in tbl_appointments. ON both I got the same error.

Comment: I tried the below updates and both are working for me

Comment: update tbl_appointments
    set slotid=0
   where apptid=2
  
      update tbl_appointments
     set firstname ='XXX'
     where apptid=1

Answer (score 0):

A better way to compute `totalmembers` is to create and use an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_timeslots_with_totalmembers
WITH SCHEMA_BINDING
AS
SELECT  a.slotid, COUNT_BIG(*) AS totalmembers
FROM    dbo.tbl_appointments a
GROUP BY a.slotid
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IUC_vw_timeslots_with_totalmembers_slotid
ON dbo.vw_timeslots_with_totalmembers (slotid)
GO

DECLARE @slotid INT = 123
SELECT  totalmembers
FROM    dbo.vw_timeslots_with_totalmembers WITH(NOEXPAND) -- This table hint is needed in order to force usage of indexed view
WHERE   slotid = @slotid
GO
```

Note: please read following notes regarding the proper configuration of `SET`tings (see section `Required SET Options for Indexed Views`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx .

Note #2: if last `SELECT` statement returns 0 rows this means that current slot doesn't have appointments (I assume that current slot is valid).

Comment: Taking into consideration that only 1% of the updates to tbl_appointments are on the slotid field, doesnt this solution add alot of unnesesary overhead in terms of index maintenance and problems with locks ?

Comment: Any index comes with an overhead but this'll be smaller than trigger's overhead.

Comment: From my point on view, any declarative solution (ex. indexed view) should be better less overhead) compared with a "similar" imperative approach (trigger in this case).